# Is this a case of reputation bias?

Tags: discussion, answers, reputation, upvotes, fastest-gun

I answered a question with some lovely diagrams and a full explanation of the method I took to solve the problem. I was about 2 minutes behind a post that simply posted some fix code and not much else from a high-rep user, and they get 4 upvotes soon after, where I remained on 0 until hours later.

I do get the accepted answer from the OP, but due to low rep they can't up vote (yet).

See screenshot;

[image: Rep Bias?]

Does anyone else see this kind of bias against low-rep members?

By the way, I don't think it's high-rep user's fault at all; they answered the question as you might expect.

Comment: When was the answer accepted? Mouse over the checkmark to find out.

Comment: One example post does not evidence make.

Comment: That's not reputation bias, only voters who think *Try this* followed by code makes a good answer. Maybe that will change someday. Maybe not.

Comment: Your answer was posted on 2014-08-26 15:44:41Z and the other answer was posted on 2014-08-26 15:37:01Z. That's more than 7 minutes, quite different from the 2 minutes you say. Fastest Gun in the West Problem, like @martin says in his answer.

Comment: The other guy did it with less code *and* a fiddle that instantly demonstrates that it works *and* posted it before yours.  SO users tend to like that.

Comment: Personally, I prefer j08691's code. It's shorter and arguably cleaner. However, your answer has an better explanation. That's a +1 to both...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can understand you and I have had similar experience. However, I also had it the other way around. I pretty much think this is related to the [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem).

When you have the first (correct and reasonably complete) answer on a question, other people who want to answer the question will upvote your answer (some even upvote all correct answers posted within a short timeframe). At that point, they leave the question and usually do not return. If you now post a better and more thorough answer, you are too late for the early voters.

Unfortunately, high-rep users are good, fast and answer the question reasonably well (whereas I check one or two facts that they know by heart) and tend to produce shorter or interesting solutions. Sometimes this is also taken into account when voting.

You might get more upvotes in due time, when people stumble over the question and appreciate your work. On the other hand, you might not.

In any case, keep up the nice work!.

Answer (score 7):

Until you adding your diagram, your answer was functionally the same as the other one which was posted a few minutes before yours. Therefore what you are seeing is an example of the the [Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) problem (as martin points out in his answer), and not people voting based on the reputation of the poster. In addition the other answer has a jsFiddle link which may also have an effect.

You have done the right thing in improving your answer and hopefully will now see a slow but steady reputation gain from it.

Basically, don't worry about this.